# How to map <C-Space> to both g:ycm_key_list_select_completion and <c-n><c-p>?

Tags: vim, key-bindings, youcompleteme

How to map <kbd>C-Space</kbd> to both g:ycm_key_list_select_completion and <kbd>c-n</kbd><kbd>c-p</kbd>?

It seems like I can't get both working. What I want is : if there is no popup yet, <kbd>C-Space</kbd> should trigger <kbd>c-n</kbd><kbd>c-p</kbd>

but if there is already a popup shown, then it should cycle through the proposition.

Comment: Would SuperTab be able to accomplish what you need?

Comment: Would it be compatible with Ultisnips' <Tab> expansion too (the vanilla one, not the ycm ultisnips completer)?

Comment: Not sure.  I do not use ycm or ultisnips, and haven't done much in the way of configuring supertab beyond just selecting the completion command.